# react native unfocus TextInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I want to make a search bar in react-native like that :

[image]

If I click on icon, I focus on textInput, but if I click on other part of screen, unfocus the textInput.

The focus part is working with the `ref`, but I don't know if it's possible to unfocus the textinput when I click in other part of the screen.

```
<TextInput
    multiline={false}
    onChangeText={(text) => onChangeText(text)}
    placeholder="search"
    style={styles.textInput}
    value={value}
    ref={research}
></TextInput>
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>research.current.focus()}>
    <Ionicons name="md-search" size={24} ></Ionicons>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just dismiss the keyboard

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'

<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        [your code in here]
    </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```